# ng-value is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    
      <div ng-app="" >
        <input ng-value="100">
        <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-value='a'>
          <option value='a'>a</option>
          <option value='b'>b</option>
          <option value='c'>c</option>
          <option value='d'>d</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here i'm getting the value using ng-value through input text,but i'm not able to get the same using select...please help me out and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you should understand:

1. `ng-value` is not a way to set the value in any dropdown. `ng-value` is a directive around the `value` attribute. To set the options correctly, the proper way is to:
   `<option selected="selected">`
2. To handle your current scenario, as pointed out, 
   `<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName='a'">` is the way to. Here, you will be setting the ng-model value to  the required value. ng-model should be set when you want to show a default value for select in angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use ng-value in a `<select>` you have to use `ng-value` in `<option>`.

And if you want to default selected value use `ng-init`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **`ng-init`** and set the **`selectedName`** as 'a'

```
 <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName='a'">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="" >
        <input ng-value="100">
        <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName='a'">
          <option value='a'>a</option>
          <option value='b'>b</option>
          <option value='c'>c</option>
          <option value='d'>d</option>
        </select>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try **ng-init** for setting default value

```
   <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName='b'"/ >
```

Answer (score 1):

> instead of using ng-init. you can assign the value to `ng-model` on `ng-value` , like 
>   `ng-value={{selectedName='a'}}`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    
      <div ng-app="" >
        <input ng-value="100">
        <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-value={{selectedName='a'}}>
          <option value='a'>a</option>
          <option value='b'>b</option>
          <option value='c'>c</option>
          <option value='d'>d</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```